# Increment value in the list based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am preparing code for my personal use which will based on historical lottery numbers give percentage part in each group of numbers. I have divided set of lottery available numbers into three groups:

`first_group = [1,2,3,4,5,6,17,18,19,20,21,33,34,35,36,37]
second_group = [7,8,9,10,11,12,22,23,24,25,26,38,39,40,41,42]
third_group = [13,14,15,16,27,28,29,30,31,32,43,44,45,46,47,48,49]`

`original numbers.txt` contain database of all lotteries from the begin

```
my_list = []

with open('original numbers.txt') as f:
   lines=f.readlines()
   for line in lines:
       my_array = np.fromstring(line, dtype=int, sep=' ')
       my_list.append(my_array)``
```

Code loop through each line of file and assign 1,2,3 value depends on which group it belongs to.

`for line in my_list:
    for num in line:
        if num in first_group:
            new_set.append(1)
        elif num in second_group:
            new_set.append(2)
        elif num in third_group:
            new_set.append(3)`

Now the part where I can't go further. I have set conditions if sum of 1,2,3 in each lottery draw is greater than 4 it will increase `dash` value which is denominator for each group to count percentage value.

```
count = Counter(new_set)

'''example
   5    21  28  31  33  41
   1     1   3   3   1   2'''

if count[1] == 4:
    rash_one += 1
    for x,y in line,new_set:
        if y == 1:


elif count[2] == 4:
    rash_two +=1
elif count[3] == 4:
    rash_three +=1``
```

What I want to accomplish is to create `list` or `dict` for 1-49 numbers and increment them with count value. So for example if there was lottery draws in which dominated mostly first group I have `rash_one = 10` and there were number 2 which was drawn 3 times and 17 which was drawn 4 times. So it gives us 30% for nr 2 and 40% for nr 17.

MY CODE (so far):

```
 import numpy as np
 from collections import Counter

 my_list = []

 with open('original numbers.txt') as f:
    lines=f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
       my_array = np.fromstring(line, dtype=int, sep=' ')
       my_list.append(my_array)

 first_group = [1,2,3,4,5,6,17,18,19,20,21,33,34,35,36,37]
 second_group = [7,8,9,10,11,12,22,23,24,25,26,38,39,40,41,42]
 third_group = [13,14,15,16,27,28,29,30,31,32,43,44,45,46,47,48,49]
 rash_one = 0
 rash_two = 0
 rash_three = 0
 new_set = []

 for line in my_list:
    for num in line:
        if num in first_group:
            new_set.append(1)
        elif num in second_group:
            new_set.append(2)
        elif num in third_group:
           new_set.append(3)

count = Counter(new_set)

'''example
   5    21  28  31  33  41
   1     1   3   3   1   2'''

if count[1] == 4:
    rash_one += 1
    for x,y in line,new_set:
        if y == 1:
        '''stopped here'''

elif count[2] == 4:
    rash_two +=1
elif count[3] == 4:
    rash_three +=1``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

```
from collections import defaultdict

first_data_group = defaultdict(int)
second_data_group = defaultdict(int)
third_data_group = defaultdict(int)

if count[1] == 4:
    print(new_set)
    rash_one += 1
    for x,y in zip(line,new_set):
        if y == 1:
            first_data_group[x] += 1


elif count[2] == 4:
    rash_two +=1
    for x,y in zip(line,new_set):
        if y == 2:
            second_data_group[x] += 1

elif count[3] == 4:
    rash_three +=1
    for x,y in zip(line,new_set):
        if y == 3:
            third_data_group[x] += 1
```